# Django outputs CSRF token as object instead of value

Tags: django, django-forms, csrf, django-csrf

I am struggling with the CSRF token in a simple POST form in Django. The template generates the following CSRF output instead of outputting the value of the token:

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='{'csrf_token':django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1255690>}' />
```

I am using `{% csrf_token %}` in the template, how can I fix this? (I am using Django 1.2)

EDIT: the exact form code is:

```
<form name="foo" action="url" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}

   <select>
       {% for key, account in accounts.items %} 
           <option value="{{ key }}">{{ account }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
   </select>
<input type="submit">    
</form>
```

Comment: Please show the exact template fragment.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have added the form, hope this helps. When I do {{ crsf_token.csrf_token }} then the actual token is shown, however without the entire hidden input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause: in settings.py I had added: `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`
but not: `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware`.

So add `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware` after `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` and `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware` and you are good to go.